# Cannot Import repository from exported xml file in PDI 4.4

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I use spoon 4.4 and database repository based SQL Server 2008 on Windows 11. JAVA version is 1.8. I can export subdirectory tree to a xml file encoding="UTF-8". The file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<repository>

<transformations>
<transformation>
  <info>
    <name>导入什么东西</name>
    <description/>
    <extended_description>这是说明</extended_description>
    <trans_version/>
    <trans_type>Normal</trans_type>
    <trans_status>0</trans_status>
    <directory>&#47;某单位20150818&#47;10500--导入分析数据&#47;10500100--历史核算结果</directory>
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
    <log>
<trans-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<size_limit_lines/>
<interval/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>TRANSNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>TRANSNAME</name></field><field><id>STATUS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STATUS</name></field><field><id>LINES_READ</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_READ</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_WRITTEN</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_WRITTEN</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_UPDATED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_UPDATED</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_INPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_INPUT</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_OUTPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_OUTPUT</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_REJECTED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_REJECTED</name><subject/></field><field><id>ERRORS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ERRORS</name></field><field><id>STARTDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STARTDATE</name></field><field><id>ENDDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ENDDATE</name></field><field><id>LOGDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOGDATE</name></field><field><id>DEPDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>DEPDATE</name></field><field><id>REPLAYDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>REPLAYDATE</name></field><field><id>LOG_FIELD</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_FIELD</name></field></trans-log-table>
<perf-log-table><connection/>
```

But when I import this XML using Tools -> Repository -> Import Repository, I get errors:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: f
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:617)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:507)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:456)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:275)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.RepositoryExportSaxParser.parse(RepositoryExportSaxParser.java:68)
    at org.pentaho.di.repository.RepositoryImporter.importAll(RepositoryImporter.java:126)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.repository.dialog.RepositoryImportProgressDialog$3.run(RepositoryImportProgressDialog.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.repository.dialog.RepositoryImportProgressDialog.open(RepositoryImportProgressDialog.java:190)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.importDirectoryToRepository(Spoon.java:4879)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:139)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:123)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:26)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1221)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7044)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:8304)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:580)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
```

What about this? Thank you.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_401"

Comment: I got it. Because xml file name inlcudes Chinese chars.